# TypeScript: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in [null]

Tags: typescript

> `Error: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in [null].`

```
class A implements OnInit {
    stringArr: string[];

    ngOnInit() {
        for(let i=0; i<4; i++) {
            this.stringArr.push("aaa");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The array needs to be initialized:

```
stringArr = [];
```

Comment: I should print this and post on my desk.

Answer (score 31):

For me the syntax was a little more than the accepted answer because I was using a full array type.

```
stringArr: Array<string> = [];
```

Also, this would work too

```
stringArr: string[] = [];
```

Just 2 ways to type a new array

Comment: "string" is the TypeScript string type, rather than "String".

Answer (score 1):

```
class A implements OnInit {
    stringArr: string=[];
    ngOnInit() {
        for(let i=0; i<4; i++) {
            this.stringArr.push("aaa");
        }
    }
}
```

Here `stringArr` is defined as string, but not as an array of string. Define  `stringArr` as blank array [].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please fix the formatting of your code block.