# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, push

I have been trying to figure out that how to insert list of into array and push new data into same array.

```
collectionList: [any]; 

//Array defined
  collection: [ 
      {
        Name:any,
        Code:any,
        Location:any,
        Capacity:number,
        Remaining:number

      }
  ]
// Getting data from database in collection array to push inside arrayList
this.collection=[{
      Name:item.Name,
      Code:item.Code,
      Location:item.Location,
      Capacity:item.Capacity,
      Remaining:item.Remaining
    }]

//Then Pushing data to collectionList

if (item.register== true){

      this.collectionList.push(this.collection)

    }
```

[MyOrigional code](https://codeshare.io/5gW1JD)

Comment: Please consider editing the code above to constitute a true self-contained [mcve] with no external dependencies or missing code (links to external sites don't really meet this need).  My *guess* about this code is that you've defined the *type* of `collectionList` without actually initializing it (which would be caught if you compile TS with `--strict`), so it's `undefined` at runtime, and you can't call `push()` on that.  Initialize your property (e.g., `collectionList: any[] = []`) and try again?

Comment: Yeah initialization was the issue. its working Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in \[null\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689140/typescript-cannot-read-property-push-of-undefined-in-null)

Comment: I tried that one. but I was not sure how to initialize the array. And I had doubt that something was missing from my code.